# Constructing variable based on 2 random variables in seq_item

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

In my sequence Item I have a bus which should contain the address and data together. Now I want to randomize the address and data, after which concatenate their randomized value in the bus. 
Please help understand how to do this, in the seqItem class.

```
class seqItem extends uvm_sequence_item;
    `uvm_object_param_utils(seqItem)

    rand logic [541-1:515] wfifo_addr;
    rand logic [512-1:0]  wfifo_data;
    logic [541-1:0] wfifo_dout; // = {this.wfifo_addr, 3'b000, this.wfifo_data};

    constraint wfifo_addr_ctrl {    ...    }

    constraint wfifo_data_ctrl {    ...    }
    …
endclass
```

So how to make `wfifo_dout` to contain the randomized values of `wfifo_addr` and `wfifo_data`. 
I have to keep separate `wfifo_addr` and `wfifo_data` signals to create randomization constraints for them.

Now I am assigning value to `wfifo_dout` from the sequence, which randomizes the seqItem transaction. However it would be nice if I could create the value of `wfifo_dout` right in seqItem.

Answer (score 4):

There are two things you can do:

1. Create a `post_randomize()` method that makes an assignment to `wfifo_dout`

   ```
   function post_randomize(); // called automatically after a call to randomize();
     wfifo_dout = {this.wfifo_addr, 3'b000, this.wfifo_data};
   endfunction
   ```
2. Use the `let` statement to declare the address and data instead of making them separate variables

   ```
   rand logic [541-1:0] wfifo_dout; 
   let wfifo_addr = wfifo_dout[541-1:515];
   let wfifo_data = wfifo_dout[512-1:0];
   ```